# Write user defined Tensor data to json object using nlohman json

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am trying to write some complex structures into json file. In that course, I have a struct as below -

```
struct State {
   std::vector<float> array1;
   std::vector<structA> array2;
   Tensor tensor1;
}
```

For the vectors in the struct, I am able to write the values into json objects like below.

```
State stateObj; 

frameJson["arrays"] = {{"array1", stateObj.array1},
                       {"array2", stateObj.array2}}
```

I use `to_json()`for custom data types.

With the `Tensor`, the class only provides a pointer to the data with a `getPointer()` method and I have the tensor size and shape information. With this pointer how do I create a json object, which has the below format. I just want to store the floating point values from the tensor object.

```
{"tensor", [Tensor data array]}
```

Comment: Do you have size too, or sentinel value?

Comment: Yes I have shape information, and also the size of the array. Have edited the question

Comment: Something along `void to_json(json& j, const Tensor& t) { for (int i = 0; i != t.size(); ++i) { j.emplace_back(t.data()[i]);} }`?

Comment: Awsm, thanks, widened my perspective on how to extensively use `to_json`